# Dataframe Groupby and Resample, with added missing rows per minute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A short data frame I want to:

1. arrange it per minute
2. adding rows of missing minutes, from 09:05 to 09:20
3. then resample it every 5-minute

   ```
   time  cars     flow
    0  9:07   737       In
    1  9:06    22      Out
    2  9:18    42       In
    3  9:19    36  Unknown
   ```

What I tried:

```
data = {'time': ["9:07", "9:06", "9:18", "9:19"], 
'cars' : [737,  22, 42,36],
'flow': ["In","Out","In","Unknown"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
idx = pd.date_range("9:05", "09:20", freq="1min")
idx = idx.rename('time')

df = df.set_index('time')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

df = df.groupby('flow').resample('5T')['cars'].sum()     # how_many_volume
print(df)
```

It returns:

```
flow     time               
0        2020-10-21 09:05:00      0
         2020-10-21 09:10:00      0
         2020-10-21 09:15:00      0
         2020-10-21 09:20:00      0
In       2020-10-21 09:05:00    737
         2020-10-21 09:10:00      0
         2020-10-21 09:15:00     42
Out      2020-10-21 09:05:00     22
Unknown  2020-10-21 09:15:00     36
```

But what's wanted is:

```
In             2020-10-21 09:05:00    737
               2020-10-21 09:10:00    0
               2020-10-21 09:15:00    42
               2020-10-21 09:20:00    0
Out            2020-10-21 09:05:00    22
               2020-10-21 09:10:00    0
               2020-10-21 09:15:00    0
               2020-10-21 09:20:00    0
Unknown        2020-10-21 09:05:00    0
               2020-10-21 09:10:00    0
               2020-10-21 09:15:00    36
               2020-10-21 09:20:00    0
```

What's the way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 = df.pivot(columns='flow').resample('5T').sum().stack()
df2.index = df2.index.swaplevel(0, 1)
>>> df2.sort_index()
                              cars
flow    time                      
In      2020-10-20 09:05:00  737.0
        2020-10-20 09:10:00    0.0
        2020-10-20 09:15:00   42.0
Out     2020-10-20 09:05:00   22.0
        2020-10-20 09:10:00    0.0
        2020-10-20 09:15:00    0.0
Unknown 2020-10-20 09:05:00    0.0
        2020-10-20 09:10:00    0.0
        2020-10-20 09:15:00   36.0
```

I would personally have left the data in its tabular form:

```
>>> df.pivot(columns='flow').resample('5T').sum()
                      cars              
flow                    In   Out Unknown
time                                    
2020-10-20 09:05:00  737.0  22.0     0.0
2020-10-20 09:10:00    0.0   0.0     0.0
2020-10-20 09:15:00   42.0   0.0    36.0
```

Comment: marvelous! thank you for the guidance! in case the 'time' column has duplicates but their 'cars' need to be included in calculation, it gives "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". How can it be resolved?

Comment: First do a `grouby.sum`, e.g. `df.reset_index().groupby(['time', 'flow']).sum().unstack().resample('5T').sum()`

Comment: thanks again for your patience and time, which benefit all the learners!

Comment: I'm happy to help!